# Illegal exception when when assigning a value to a double c++ linux x86-64

Tags: c++, linux, illegal-instruction

When running this simple program I get an Illegal instruction error

```
struct params{
    double resf{};
};

int foo(params& params)
{
    params.resf = 0.05;
}

int main()
{
    params params;
    foo(params);
}
```

EDIT:
changing the return type from int to void causes everything to work, despite the wrong return type seeming to be unrelated

Comment: `foo` claims to return an `int` but doesn't. Either change the declaration to return `void`, or add a proper `return` statement.

Comment: Add `-Werror=return-type` to your compiler flags for C++ if you want to catch this as a compile-time error instead of nasal daemons at runtime.

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output.

Comment: If you promise to return something and then fall off the end of the function without doing so, a C++ compiler will not generate a return instruction at the end of the function and you will continue executing something in the following memory. If you are lucky, this will result in a crash (gcc and clang sometimes generate an explicit invalid instruction there as a courtesy).

Comment: "_despite the wrong return type seeming to be unrelated_": It is very much related. In C++ falling off the end of a function declared with non-`void` return type is always undefined behavior and compilers can assume that it will never happen and optimize accordingly. That's different from C, where falling off the end of such a function only causes undefined behavior if the return value is used at the call site.